# How to reply to specific comment using django recursive relationship and react js

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework

Model is

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    reply = models.ForeignKey('Comment',null=True,related_name="replies",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

adding and showing comment using react

```
class CommentExampleComment extends Component {
state={
  comment:'',
  id:''
}
changeHandler=event=>{
  var vals =event.target.value
  // var jpt = {...this.state.comment}
  // this.props.comments.map(el=>(this.setState({
  //   comment:vals,
  //   id:el.id
  this.setState({comment:vals})
    // file:event.target.files
}
submitHandler=e=>{
  e.preventDefault()
  var formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('content',this.state.comment)
  formData.append('id',this.actionInput.value)
//used to add comment to db
  axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/api/comments/1',formData).then(res=>{ 
    console.log(res.data)
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
  })
// used for showing comment 
  this.props.onShowComment()
}
return(
      <Aux>
      <br></br>


        // THIS IS COMMENT SECTION
        <div class="main-comment-section">
            <form method="POST" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
      <textarea id="w3mission" onChange = {this.changeHandler} rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                <button name ="button">Comment</button>
            </form>
            {this.props.comments.map(el=>(
        <div>
        <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p class="mb-0">{ el.content }</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer">-by <cite title="Source Title"></cite></footer>
            </blockquote>
                <blockquote class="blockquote">
                    <p class="mb-0"></p>
                    <footer class="blockquote-footer">-by <cite title="Source Title"></cite></footer>
                </blockquote> */}

                //THIS IS REPLY SECTION
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <form method="post" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>

           <h1>{el.id}</h1>
                     <input type="hidden" name="id" ref={(input) => { this.actionInput = input }} value ={el.id}/>

                <textarea id="w3mission" onChange = {this.changeHandler} rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>

                     <button name ="button">Reply</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
             </div>
      ))}
        </div>
    </Aux>)}}
var mapStateToProps = state=>{
  return{
    comments:state.cmnts.comment
  }
}
var mapDispatchToProps = dispatch=>{
  return{
    onShowComment:()=>dispatch(actions.commentList())
  }
}
export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( CommentExampleComment );
PROBLEM IS :
```

when i try to submit the reply value passed through hidden field "(input type="hidden" name="id" ref={(input) => { this.actionInput = input }} value ={el.id})"is always the last comment id but i want the value of the comment id to be id corresponding to that particular comment.I want the value to capture the comment id while replying to that comment

Answer (score 2):

onChange = {e => this.changeHandler(e, el.id) }

grab el.id on changeHandler and store in state, use this state in your api call.